# SSAS 2012, showing duplicate names when querying in Excel

Tags: ssas, ssas-2012

I need some basic help with SSAS 2012. I have my employees dimension. Here is an example:
[image]

Here is my hierarchy, the default one when creating the dimension:

[image]

My problem is that when querying the cube through excel, when showing only the name, it appears twice. I know it has two different IDs, but I am not showing the ID, just the Name in the columns and a value in the Metrics. 
It appears like this:

[image]

How do I make it group correctly?

Thanks

Comment: What is the employee CODE value for the two example employee dimension rows? What is the "key column" property set to for Employee Code in the SSAS attribute properties?

Comment: The value for code is JDOE, the key column property is Employee Key and Employee Code

Comment: Although the code value is the same, the KEY value is different, hence you will see two rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the KeyColumns of the Employee Code attribute to just the Employee Code field (the column called Name on your table). Including Employee Key as the key in the Employee Code attribute is the issue. It should just be in the KeyColumns for the EMPE KEY attribute.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. I had to do a little clean up of the code, since it was generating a duplicate attribute, because of some space and enter characters in the data.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any problem in your dimension in the technical perspective. 
If you just need a distinct value in Excel, you just need to configure the pivot table property to 'group' the duplicate name:
Right click the pivot table in Excel book, find the menu over there.